# Need proper documentation for R Kelly Remix gem - Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing

I am working with Nokogiri to extract javascript out of a page. The script looks like this:-

```
P.when('A').register("ImageBlockATF", function(A){
var data = {
            'colorImages': { 'initial': [{"hiRes":null,"thumb":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41947FUviFL._SS40_.jpg","large":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41947FUviFL.jpg","main":{"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41947FUviFL._SX355_.jpg":[347,355],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41947FUviFL._SX450_.jpg":[440,450],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41947FUviFL._SX425_.jpg":[416,425],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41947FUviFL._SX466_.jpg":[456,466],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41947FUviFL.jpg":[489,500]},"variant":"MAIN","lowRes":null},{"hiRes":null,"thumb":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31SqBz2H7EL._SS40_.jpg","large":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31SqBz2H7EL.jpg","main":{"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31SqBz2H7EL._SX355_.jpg":[302,355],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31SqBz2H7EL._SX450_.jpg":[383,450],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31SqBz2H7EL._SX425_.jpg":[361,425],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31SqBz2H7EL._SX466_.jpg":[396,466],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31SqBz2H7EL.jpg":[425,500]},"variant":"PT01","lowRes":null},{"hiRes":null,"thumb":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31Cw2c6RFsL._SS40_.jpg","large":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31Cw2c6RFsL.jpg","main":{"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31Cw2c6RFsL._SX355_.jpg":[192,355],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31Cw2c6RFsL._SX450_.jpg":[244,450],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31Cw2c6RFsL._SX425_.jpg":[230,425],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31Cw2c6RFsL._SX466_.jpg":[253,466],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31Cw2c6RFsL.jpg":[271,500]},"variant":"PT02","lowRes":null},{"hiRes":null,"thumb":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51wYWSUvN8L._SS40_.jpg","large":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51wYWSUvN8L.jpg","main":{"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51wYWSUvN8L._SX355_.jpg":[222,355],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51wYWSUvN8L._SX450_.jpg":[281,450],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51wYWSUvN8L._SX425_.jpg":[265,425],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51wYWSUvN8L._SX466_.jpg":[291,466],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51wYWSUvN8L.jpg":[312,500]},"variant":"PT03","lowRes":null},{"hiRes":null,"thumb":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31BY-dyDpWL._SS40_.jpg","large":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31BY-dyDpWL.jpg","main":{"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31BY-dyDpWL._SX355_.jpg":[222,355],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31BY-dyDpWL._SX450_.jpg":[281,450],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31BY-dyDpWL._SX425_.jpg":[265,425],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31BY-dyDpWL._SX466_.jpg":[291,466],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31BY-dyDpWL.jpg":[312,500]},"variant":"PT04","lowRes":null}]},
            'colorToAsin': {'initial': {}},
            'holderRatio': 1.0,
            'holderMaxHeight': 700,
            'heroImage': {'initial': []},
            'heroVideo': {'initial': []},
            'spin360ColorData': {'initial': {}},
            'spin360ColorEnabled': {'initial': 0},
            'spin360ConfigEnabled': false,
            'playVideoInImmersiveView':'false',
            'tabbedImmersiveViewTreatment':'T2',
            'totalVideoCount':'0',
            'videoIngressATFSlateThumbURL':'',
            'mediaTypeCount':'0',
            'atfEnhancedHoverOverlay' : true,
            'weblabs' : {},
            'aibExp3Layout' : 1,
            'aibRuleName' : 'R18'
            };
A.trigger('P.AboveTheFold'); // trigger ATF event.
return data;
});
```

I need to extract the value of 'data'. How can I use the R Kelly gem to do so.

I know this can be achieved using RegEX as well. But this is just a sample script. The page I am working on actually contains much more data like this with tons of variables. Therefore I need to find a legit way of extracting data.

I have been searching online for over a day now but couldn't find much helpful information on how to use the R-Kelly gem.

Comment: LOL.  Thought this was an April Fool's prant, but lo and behold: https://github.com/tenderlove/rkelly and https://github.com/nene/rkelly-remix.  Guess if you believe, you can fly...

Comment: Lol. no it was not an April Fools prank. I have been through the documentation you provided. However it is very little and covers only small functionality of this gem. It does not cover the entire capabilities and how I solve the problem stated above. Thanks for the try though.